# Compile xf86-video-ati on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, compiling, amd-graphics

How  to compile  `xf86-video-ati` from https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-ati/  on **Ubuntu 16.04** ?

Answer (score 1):

you can check this repository.
open terminal ,add the following repository

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
 sudo apt-get update
```

This PPA provides updated X (2D) and mesa (3D) free graphics drivers for radeon, intel and nvidia hardware.

https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

Comment: @George there is "Adding this PPA to your system" section near the bottom. also I've edited my comment to include them.

Comment: Does the link have a "how to" section?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install git autoconf xutils-dev xorg-dev libtool
git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-ati
cd xf86-video-ati/
./autogen.sh 
make
```